# Excel for mac stuck at "upload pending" when saving a file

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, onedrive

The file in question is a shared file from another user in onedrive. I usually perform "open in app" on the onedrive web interface. This has worked for me for a long time.

However not sure what happened, but after my recent changes to the file, it is just stuck in "upload pending" state.

Another observation, I am also no longer seeing any updates made by other users on the same file.

I tried

1. CLosing my local file and reopening from onedrive. Did Not work.
2. Clearing cache of one drive from browser, hoping it would clear my local copy somewhere. Did Not work
3. Looked for the app cache of the excel on my mac, hoping to clear it, so that excel will re-download from onedrive. Can't seem to locate it.

How can i recover from this state? I dont really want to use the excel web interface, isn't as smooth or powerful as the desktop version.

Comment: Have you logged out of onedrive and logged back in? Does onedrive pick up any file sync errors? Maybe your sync failed while offline and excel doesnt know how to merge the changes. Maybe save yours as an offline copy and try opening again from scratch (remove shared folder from local pc, press sync button again on shared folder from onedrive web client)

Comment: @Mobus - thanks for the suggestion, tried this, didnt help, probably because the file was never synced to my one drive on desktop, since its a shared file from another user.

Answer (score 2):

Please note the instructions below may reset some preferences and will delete pending documents that have yet to be uploaded to O365.

1. Quit Excel if it is open.
2. Click on Finder in the dock to open a file
   browser
3. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to open the Go To window. Paste this into
   the text field: `~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel`
4. You should see one folder "Data". Trash it.
5. Open Excel.

Excel should show the first-time welcome screen and your recent documents will no longer be pending upload. If you wish to undo this change, move the Data folder from the trash back into the `~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel` folder from step 3.

Ref.: From [Tech Community Microsoft Site](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365/powerpoint-for-mac-how-to-remove-quot-upload-pending-quot-items/m-p/1489987)

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me — for PowerPoint. To avoid losing changes I'd recommend saving a copy of the file to your local drive **before starting the procedure**.